# How to handle the special characters using java or javascript without removal

Tags: java, encryption, architecture

I am developing a rich text editor to one of our distributed application to allow the user to enter his/her comments in that editor. Here we are allowing the user to type the comments from keyboard and copy paste the comments from external sources like internet, MS-Word etc., So, here we need to save the content whatever entered by the user without removing even a single character.

Initially I thought like, we need to encrypt the comments and save it to the database side, while user wants to see his comments, then we get it from the database and decrypting it and displaying to the user. But by this the problem is like, the encrypted data/comments in the database is used by different applications so that we need to implement the same encryption and decryption mechanism in all other applications....It's a very bad idea.

So guys, If any one have the better idea on this. please post the answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By ["encrypt"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) I'm assuming you mean ["escape" or "encode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)?

Otherwise, why would you need to encrypt comments? Keep in mind that you won't be able to perform database searches on the encrypted data. Also, if an attacker was to gain access to your database and at the same time reverse engineer your application he/she would still be able to decrypt the data. From the little detail you give about your application, it makes no sense to encrypt simple "comments".

It is generally better to store the raw data in the database and escape it when displaying it to the user. For instance, let's say you want to escape HTML in the text the user inputs into your database. So you have escaped all HTML tags before inserting the text. But a year later you want to improve one of your applications and allow `<b>` and `<i>` for this one particular application. In such cases it's more preferable to have access to the original raw data in the database, and do any escaping right when you need to, i.e. before displaying it to the user.

You can read more on this subject [here](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/).

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer. Yes of course every time the requirement will change if we consider few characters should allow and few are not. That's why we didn't care about any special characters we have to save the raw data whatever user had entered. Here the total problem is coming with the special characters especially extended ascii charaters.